# Resize icon to fit container element?

Tags: javascript, css, icons, webfonts

The icon is part of a font from http://fontello.com/

So it's basically text. I've read many questions here about resizing text to fit the container element and there aren't any solutions it seems.

But the thing is that the icon is slightly different - it's always a single character. I was wondering this makes it possible to somehow resize it to 100% size of the container element. Because I only need to find out the size of a character, and not a variable-length string.

Any ideas on how could I do that?

Comment: Seems an unlikely requirement. Could you explain the reasoning why the element should need to confirm that way?

Comment: Think of thumbnails for let's say albums. If an album doesn't have a thumbnail image, I want to display an icon. But I want the icon to scale to the thumbnail container size. Because the container may have variable size, depending on the current screen resolution etc. Right now I'm doing this with a background image and background-size property, but I wanted to use an icon because it scales nicely

Comment: So if no thumbnail exists you're adding an icon...but you need that to be 100% of the thumbnail size? Not sure an icon font is what you are after but this will definitely required JS/JQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest i can think of getting with pure CSS is something like:

```
.container {
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
    border:1px solid red;
    font-size: 100px;
}

.container span {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t73yT/

where you set the font-size to the size of the container, and use em's to specify container width/height. Your icon font may not have the padding and what not that normal fonts do, which might just make it work as expected (you can but try i guess).

You also have a javascript option of :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = $('div').outerWidth();
    $('div').css('fontSize', w+'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YbUef/1/

But this does pretty much the same thing, and you're limited by whatever spacing/padding is in the font-file.